# cannot borrow `original` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust

I just started learning Rust, and while I do have some C++ experience (although it's rusty) so I can understand pointers, references and stuff, I can't seem to understand this error that popped up while I was experimenting with it.

Consider the following code:

```rust
    let mut original = String::from("original value");

    {
        let next = &mut original;
        *next = String::from("next value");
        println!("\nInner scope original: \t\"{}\"", original); // <-- error here
        println!("\nInner scope next: \t\"{}\"", next);
    }

    println!("\nOuter original value: \t\"{}\"", original);
```

The compiler throws an error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `original` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

|         let next = &mut original;
|                    ------------- mutable borrow occurs here
|         *next = String::from("next value");
|         println!("\nInner scope original: \t\"{}\"", original);
|                                                      ^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
|         println!("\nInner scope next: \t\"{}\"", next);
|                                                  ---- mutable borrow later used here
|
= note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

But if I only switch the order of lines like this:

```rust
    let mut original = String::from("original value");

    {
        let next = &mut original;
        *next = String::from("next value");
        println!("\nInner scope next: \t\"{}\"", next);
        println!("\nInner scope original: \t\"{}\"", original); // <-- no error
    }

    println!("\nOuter original value: \t\"{}\"", original);
```

...then it works fine.
How are those two different, considering neither of them mutates anything, and why does the compiler throw an error in one case, but not the other?

The error is also thrown if I try to print the `original` value before mutating:

```rust
    let mut original = String::from("original value");

    {
        let next = &mut original;
        println!("\nInner scope original: \t\"{}\"", original); // <-- error here
        *next = String::from("next value");
        println!("\nInner scope next: \t\"{}\"", next);
    }

    println!("\nOuter original value: \t\"{}\"", original);
```

I'm sure there is a logical explanation obvious to you guys with more Rust experience.

Comment: The borrow checker isn't perfect, and will err on the side of false positives to try to ensure it doesn't give any false negatives. Because of the "you can only have one mutable reference" rule, the compiler is trying to verify that `next` is done being used before it allows the `original` to be used. I can't give a very good technical explanation on how it decides that, though.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows, I disagree. The borrow checker perfectly works fine. It's one of the basic rules: While there is a mutable reference, no borrowing is allowed. This rule simply prevents programs from going to race conditions. Imaging your program is trying to mutate a value, at the same time what is the current value? It's unknown til the mutating task is done. Again, this means while there is a mutation, any reading value results are unknown.

Comment: @Mr.R I didn't mean to disagree with how the borrow checker works, I just meant that while a *programmer* could go through this example and verify that there is no data race, the borrow checker follows its rules regardless, and we need to work around that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust considers that the exclusive reference `next` to `original` exists from the line where it is created until the **last** time it is used.
As long as `next` exists, no other reference (shared or mutable) to `original` can be taken; this is the main constraint of borrow-checking.
Printing internally uses shared references to the printed data, thus the error.

This explains that when you swap some lines, you see that some of them which were rejected are now accepted since they now appear after the last usage of `next`.

You could object that the last usage of `next` does not require a mutation; it's true, but the rule is that such mutation **could** occur as long as the exclusive reference exists.

Note that the braces you introduced in your code probably come from an old example, when the lifetime analysis relied on *scopes*; at that time, it was recommended to explicitly narrow the scopes in order to reduce potential conflicts.
Now, there is a non-lexical lifetime analysis that automatically narrows the portion of code where multiple borrows can conflict; this portion stops at the last usage of the reference, not at the end of the scope (these braces are not anymore useful).
This is what you experienced when swapping lines.

Comment: So if you acquired a reference to a variable, there is no reason to use the original reference while you have the reference that you acquired. Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @DejanJanjušević yes, generally a simple example like this with local variables referring to the variable just above is not similar to real cases. It is much more common to take the reference as the parameter for a function, or for iterations (`.iter_mut()`).